# Search based on any combination of attributes

Tags: java, generics, search

I have a file system FileSystem that contains files in the form of the matrix. Each of these files have the following 4 attributes:

- size;
- name;
- timeCreated;
- permission;

I need to implement search  based on any combination of attributes.

Instead of defining separate search method for each combination of criteria, I thought that there has to be a way to implement generic search function.

```
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class File {
   private long size;
   private String name;
   private LocalDateTime timeCreated;
   private Permissions permission;
 }




public static void searchFilesStream() {

    System.out.println("Search files using stream: ");
    Arrays.stream(FileSystem.files)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(file -> Permissions.W.equals(file.getPermission())
                    && LocalDate.of(2022, 10, 25).isBefore(ChronoLocalDate.from(file.getTimeCreated()))
            ).map(File::getName)
            .filter(f-> f.equals("file40"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println)
    ;

}
```